# Figure counter: caption and label

Tags: captions, subcaption

I do have a general question which is why I do not provide a minimal working example for the moment.

Question: Is it possible to show a table's/figure's main caption above while writing \caption and \label below any subfigure/subtable in the code?

Reason: Whenever I write \caption followed by \label before the first \begin{subfigure}, any subfigure increases the figure counter, which is not what I want.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Use T1 font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Key value processing
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% Colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Table and figure notes
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

% Mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% For mathematical definitions
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

% Algorithms
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

% Use Times New Roman as default font
\usepackage{txfonts}

% Use Garamond as default font
%\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}

% Floats
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{placeins} 

% Header formatting
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Footnote formatting
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang,bottom]{footmisc}

% Managing table of contents appearance
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

% Managing list of abbreviation appearance
% Full name's first letter is in capital form
\usepackage{mfirstuc} 

% Change the resetting of counters
\usepackage{chngcntr}

% Advanced tables
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Flowcharts
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,fit,backgrounds}

% External tables
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

% Advanced captions
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=false]{subcaption}

% Code listings
\usepackage{listings}

% Minipages with variable lists
\usepackage{varwidth}

% Advanced table of contents formatting
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

% Formatting of ordered (enumeration) and unordered (itemize) lists
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

% Customizing of citations in the text
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}

% Advanced page layout
\usepackage{geometry}

% Hyperlinks and PDF information
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Glossaries (must be loaded after hyperref)
% Add "notree" if the self-created style is used
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nopostdot,nomain]{glossaries}

% Length calculations
\usepackage{calc}

% Allow for "Textmarker" highlighting \texthl{highlighted text}
\usepackage{soul}

% \todo Notes
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}
\usepackage{todonotes}

% Abbreviations
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% Blind texts
\usepackage{lipsum}

% English hyphenation rules
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

% Use nice quotation marks with \enquote
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Log_marginal_likelihood_25_200.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Test}
    \label{mainlabel}
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Log_marginal_likelihood_25_200.png}
        \caption{sub1}
        \label{labelsub1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Log_marginal_likelihood_25_2000.png}
        \caption{sub2}
        \label{labelsub2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

As can be seen in Figure \ref{labelsub1} and Figure \ref{labelsub2}

\end{document}
```

Actually, it seems that the template I am using makes things worse (a quite complex template as it uses a *.cls file inside a *.tex file, the cls file uses key value pairs like `\begin{figure}[caption={test},label={labeltest}]`. I checked moving the main caption of figure 2 to the bottom and the top and the subfigures always refer to the main caption/label. So I guess I might just have found the answer myself, but if anyone thinks there is a better way... happy to hear it.

Comment: Since there are several possible ways to produce subfigures, it would be helpful if you could share a MWE that shows you how currently do it and that others can use in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sure enough, happy to do so...

Comment: Added a minimal working example, but seems like this way, I cannot get any useful advice as the bug is within the template I am using.

Comment: As far as I test your document example, this is the case of it: main caption at top of figure and sub caption at bottom of subfigures. BTW, your document preamble i s a big mess. Please cleanup it (many packages are load twice with different options, `hyperref` had to be load last, etc. At cleaning ask your self, are really need all those packages in your document...

Comment: Thanks Zarko, yes the preamble is a mess since I copied them all out of the template to be sure it all works. In the example template, I checked and it seems to work... but I will clean up the preamble for sure. And I didn't know that hyperref needs to be loaded at the end. Thanks!